# How does Google Play send the "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" Broadcast?

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I am writing a custom implementation of the Google Analytics SDK for gathering data for campaigns by doing the following:

- Register a receiver which listens to the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast
- Create a custom `BroadcastReceiver` which stores the referral URL and I later send the URL to my service.

I understand the idea that when you install an app from the special Google campaign URL that Google play sends the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intent broadcast. But does that mean that any app that is listening for this broadcast will be able to see my referral URL? I can't find any documentation on this...

Answer (score 1):

The `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast can only be received by the app which was installed. When sending a broadcast you can define a target package.
Otherwise your `BroadcastReceiver` would fire up everytime you install another app.

Comment: can you post some code to prevent frequent broadcast issue when we install another app?